# Use Timezone in DB:raw queries

Tags: php, laravel

By default my laravel app is storing the dates in UTC timezone and depending on the user profile I am changing the timezone via Model accessor and everything is working fine.

The only issue is with DB::raw queries where the timezone is not changing.
Here is the example  of my query

```
  $sales=Sales::select(DB::raw('hour(created_at) AS hour'), DB::raw('COUNT(id) AS sales'))           
        ->where('created_at','>=',Carbon::now()->startOfDay())
        ->get()->groupBy(function($data) use($timezone){               
            return  Carbon::parse($data->created_at)->timezone($timezone)->format('H');
        });
```

Now here the hour is coming in UTC timezone instead of user timezone. How can I get the hour in user timezone here?

Comment: Could try using [CONVERT_TZ](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz)  to change the `created_at` being passed in the `hour` function (if using MySQL, though I'm sure other DBMS would have equivalent functions)

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks for the tip. I fixed it by using this DB::raw("hour(CONVERT_TZ(created_at,'+00:00','$timezone')) AS hour")

Answer (score 0):

your `$data->created_at` this is already a [carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) instance and it attached time zone `UTC`

but in your code your creating a new [carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) instance from user `timezone` which is wrong  `Carbon::parse()->timezone()` it create new [carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) instance from database time and add to  user timezone

so it means it get date and time `06-24-2021` and attach to `user` timezone

use

```php
return  $data->created_at->timezone($timezone)->format('H');
```

this instead here `$data->created_at` is [carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) instance attached with UTC time zone so `06-24-2021` with `UTC` time zone

then you call `->timezone($timezone)->format('H')` then it convert the timezone `UTC` to `user` timezone

Comment: Yes, Initially i tried that but i was getting  "expects parameter 1 to be string, object given" that is why i changed it.

Comment: `expects parameter 1 to be string, object given` line no. and in which function it gives ? `may be` $timezone is object here but it expect string

Comment: I fixed it by adding this DB::raw("hour(CONVERT_TZ(created_at,'+00:00','$timezone')) AS hour")

Answer (score 0):

You are not converting the hour. You are just converting the created_at but not the hour selected.

Try this:

```php
$sales = Sales::select(DB::raw('MAX(created_at) as created_at'), DB::raw('COUNT(id) AS sales'))           
        ->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->startOfDay())
        ->get()
        ->map(function($data) use($timezone) {
            $data->hour = Carbon::parse($data->created_at)
                ->timezone($timezone)
                ->format('H');

            return $data;
        })
        ->groupBy(function($data) {               
            return $data->hour;
        });
```

Comment: This query resulted in this error "In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column"

Comment: Did you use `->get()` before `->map()` and `->groupBy()` ?

Comment: This is happening because of `DB::raw('COUNT(id) AS sales')` in the select. the db does not know which row to take the `created_at` value from and associate with the `count(id)`. You will need to use an aggregation function (min, max, etc.) to select the created_at. Something like `Sales::select(DB::raw('max(created_at) as created_at', DB::raw('COUNT(id) AS sales'))`. Ive updated the answer. But Can you explain me better what you want to retrieve with the query?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I fixed with convert_tz in DB::raw